# Object contains only the public half of a key pair

Tags: certificate, client-certificates

Upon installation of a client side certificate, I am getting the exception "Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided". My application is a VC#.NET application running over an ASP.NET platform. The application also uses WSE 2.0 to import certificates into making SOAP requests.

Upon research, I've found that this exception is of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.

I am pretty positive all my WSE settings are configured correctly, since I was able to find a similar certificate by subject-distinguished-name. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was recently having the same problem. I found [one explanation here](http://www.docusign.com/forums/showthread.php?t=381) that worked for me. Specifically, the permissions for the private key. The full info is copied below.

> There are a couple things that I would
>   look at first:
>
> 1. Do you have a private key for this certificate?
> 2. Have you given permission for youf application to access the private
>      key?
>
> You can establish whether you have a
>   private key by viewing the certificate
>   through the Windows Certificate Store.
>   To get to this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. From the Windows Start menu, select Run.
> 2. Type mmc in the Open: field. Click OK
> 3. Select "Add/Remove Snap-in" from the File menu.
> 4. Click the Add button.
> 5. Select "Certificates" from the list of Available Standalone Snap-ins.
>      Click the Add button.
> 6. Select "Computer account." Click Next.
> 7. Select "Local Computer". Click Finish.
> 8. Click Close.
> 9. Click OK.
>
>    10. Expand the Certificates node under the Console Root and open the
>          Personal store.
>    11. Double-click the Certificate you're using. If you have a private
>          key, the dialog will display a message
>          at the bottom that says "You have a
>          private key that corresponds to this
>          certificate".
>
> If you have a private key, then ensure
>   that your application has permission
>   to access the key:
>
> 1. Open Windows Explorer.
> 2. Navigate to the C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application
>      Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
>      folder.
> 3. Select the files containing the keys that the WSE will need to
>      retrieve.
> 4. From the File menu, select Properties.
> 5. On the Security tab, add the ASPNET account and select th e Full
>      Control option.
> 6. Notes:
>           1. Determining which key file in the MachineKeys folder is
>      associated with a certificate can be
>      difficult. One easy method is to note
>      the creation date and time when
>      creating a new certificate. When you
>      view the files in the MachineKeys
>      directory, check the Date Modified
>      field for the corresponding date and
>      time.
>           2. If you have configured your system to run under a different
>      account than ASPNET, use that account
>      when granting permissions to access
>      the certificate.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. (I did have a private key, but my app didn't have access to it).

Comment: check this answer on how to find out which machine key corresponds to a certificate:  http://serverfault.com/a/642279/401044

Comment: I had this happen to me, but I was in Azure, I have no idea how to follow those steps on Azure :(

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience it could be failing because of two reasons.

1. Check if your cert has private key available.
2. If that is .net application then check if you have given permission to cert to make sure your application has permission to access the cert. In my case adding the "iis_iusrs" and given read permission does work for me. 
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After encountering the same exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException, Object contains only the public half of a key pair, I proofed an alternative, but less optimal solution.

Situation: Certificate / key look up worked great inside of Visual Studio IIS Express, but while the Web Application was running under the proper IIS service, I always received the 'Contains only public half of key pair' exception.

I used the WSE3 CertificateTool to locate the private key section on the filesystem and attempted at length to adjust the user permission settings to give the ASP user permissions as per the above answer.

My eventual fix, which was not pretty, was to create a new IIS Application Pool specific to my Web service code and set the user Identity the pool runs as the Local machine owner of the certificate + private key.

The final location I installed the certificate in was "Local Computer / Trusted People".

Using WSE3 CustomPolicyAssertion, C# .NET:

```
clientToken = X509TokenProvider.CreateToken(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
   StoreName.TrustedPeople, "soap.partnersite.com", X509FindType.FindBySubjectName);
```

After updating the App Pool Identity, no private key file overrides were necessary when changing the application pool owner.